# Tableau - I can't see 'Extension' in the Objects section

Tags: tableau-api

I downloaded the extension file (.trex) and saved it locally (My Tableau Repository). In a Tableau workbook, I opened a dashboard sheet and I can't see 'Extension' in the Objects section.
Anyone know why? What I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Extensions was introduced in Tableau Version 2018.2
So you will be able to see the extension object in dashboard if you have Tableau Version 2018.2 or greater.